# Lynx text browser changing the background color to match terminal emulator settings

Tags: linux, browser, arch-linux, color-profiles, lynx

Im using Sakura and I use a dark mode color scheme. The background color is a dark gray color. (#1e1e1e). I am trying to figure out how to get lynx terminal browser to match this background color. Is this possible? I've seen video where lynx background color is very close to this color. How can I enforce my terminal default color scheme when using lynx?

[image: This img of lynx has a background color is not the 'standard; black that is an option in lynx]

Comment: What setting makes it possible to display multiple scripts? My installation of lynx is not able to display scripts other than latin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The color scheme is managed by a file **lynx.lss**, which is located (of course depending on your distribution) in `/etc/lynx/`
Look for the string that starts with "normal"  and if you set it to:

```
normal:         normal:                 black:lightgray
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while and I'v actually moved on to using w3m text browser, but I might go back and try this setting in the lynx.lss.

Answer (score 0):

If lynx is build using `ncurses` you can support default-terminal color by commenting the following two lines in `/etc/lynx/lynx.lss`:

```sh
#normal:        normal:         black:lightgray
#default:       normal:         white:black
```